# How far have you been able to push a netbook's capabilities?

Tags: netbook

I recently purchased an [Acer Aspire One](http://www.acer.ca/acer/productv.do?LanguageISOCtxParam=en&kcond61e.c2att101=81358&sp=page16e&ctx2.c2att1=27&link=ln438e&CountryISOCtxParam=CA&ctx1g.c2att92=811&ctx1.att21k=1&CRC=2217899419). I'll be using it as an ultraportable supplement to my 16" laptop, which I don't like to carry around more than needed. The Aspire is a pretty standard configuration for netbooks, though with a slightly better processor and bigger hard drive. Still just 1GB memory, though.

I know that netbooks make tradeoffs in performance in order to be small and have a long battery life. I'm fine with that, as the device serves the purpose of being a convenient alternative computer. I don't really expect to be able to run Photoshop, or the full Visual Studio (plan to try the Express version though).

Now to my question: how far have you been able to push a netbook's capabilities? How "heavy" an application can you run on such a computer?

Also: will upgrading the memory be likely to make any difference, or will the system still be limited by the processor?

**UPDATE**

I had the memory upgraded to 2GB. It's noticeably snappier, though not a speedy machine by any means. It is enough to surf the web, use Office, watch videos on Youtube, and even do some light coding. Visual Studio actually works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to 2GB should help quite a bit. I have an Asus EeePC 1005HA and I upgraded from the base 1GB to 2 and there was a noticeable jump in performance. Of course, performance is still very much limited by the processor, but it's been able to handle all of my day-to-day applications while still keeping >6 hours of battery life. I haven't tried anything too system-intensive, but I've been using it like I use my main computer (minus games, of course) without a significant performance hit.

Comment: Can you share some of the applications you use on your netbook, and/or activities you perform? Coding? Graphics work? Watching videos? I could use some context!

Comment: I've done a bit of both coding and graphics (using Eclipse and GIMP on Ubuntu). Most of my day-to-day work involves word processing, but in my downtime, I watch videos or play some older 3D games (think GTA 3) and the only evidence that the computer is working harder than normal is that the fan turns on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had the memory upgraded and the machine is a little more responsive - not necessarily faster but just "feels" snappier - better for multitasking!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have an 'original' 8.9" screen AA1-150 that's been upgraded to 1.5GB RAM and is running Fedora 13. I have to say that for all general apps it is a great, small format unit and I have compiled code on it and it streams video absolutely fine. I use the netbook as a portable diagnostics tool and workstation for connecting to Linux servers via SSH and Windows servers via RDP. I have installed a VoIP softphone and have used its built in camera for video conferencing. It's obviously not a gamers' machine but apart from that it saves lugging round a full laptop when I don't need one.

Answer (score 0):

The way i have been able to push my netbook (Lenovo S10-1) WAY beyond the power of its self was with the "ONLIVE" service.  Playing Games like Unreal3 and JustCause 2

Answer (score 0):

Windows runs too slow on netbooks. Netbooks generally ship with Windows XP/7 starter versions which are slow compared to Netbook specific GNU/Linux Distributions. I have been using a Samsung N150 Netbook for 4 years now. I used Windows for a year but got irritated with the speed and limitations that the OS had. I replaced the OS with Ubuntu & Now Fedora. They are fast and have no restrictions.

As far as the capabilities are concerned, I even configured a Pentaboot system on it. And it was running just fine. Netbooks are immensely configurable devices in my opinion.